# Web spider, which is able to crawl ajax-based websites

Tags: ajax, selenium, web-crawler, crawler4j

Right now i'm using Crawler4j and i'm pretty happy with that - but it can not crawl ajax-based websites. I used selenium once for another approach and this works fine combined with phantomjs. So is there a way to plug in Selenium into crawler4j?

If not - is there another good library in Java for handling ajax based websites?

(With webspider i mean, that i have to give the program one url and it automatically starts extracting the content form the site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes. The source code of crawler4j is hosted on GitHub.

You are free to contribute an extension, so crawler4j can fetch ajax-based websites. By default **crawler4j** is not possible to fetch such sites.

[Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is able to render JS while crawling web pages as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966642/using-nutch-how-to-crawl-the-dynamic-content-of-web-page-that-are-uisng-ajax). However setting up Apache Nutch for Web-Crawling is much more work than adapting existing code structures to be used with crawler4j.